# Iterative Fibonacci code in Java?

Tags: java, iteration

I have the following for finding the nth Fibonacci number in the sequence, in Java:

```
int fib (int n) {
    int fib = 0;
    int a = 1;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        fib = fib + a;
        a = fib;
    }
    return fib;
}
```

I don't really understand this part

```
fib = fib + a;
   a = fib;
}
return fib;
```

Comment: Try printing values of `fib` and `a` in each loop and you will understand what it is doing

Comment: This appears like a homework problem.  Could you be more specific about what you don't understand?

Comment: Don Scott -  I don't really understand the return statement. Is this implemented when we get past the condition of i<n? Also, when we are assigning a to a=fib;, is this the earlier value of fib or the value of fib from fib=fib+a? Thanks.

Comment: Get your concepts cleared about recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work when the input is 2. It returns 2. However, it should be 1 i.e. fib(2) = 1 as fib(0) + fib (1) return 1.

```
int fib (int n) {
    int fib = 0;
    int a = 1;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        int temp = fib;
        fib = fib + a;
        a = temp;
    }
    return fib;
}
```

I added the temp to store the previous prev value. So to make sure the it is always adding the previous value and the previous prev value.

Answer (score 1):

As we can see

"fib" is assigned value as 1 and "a" is assigned value as 0 , this is done because as we know in Fibonacci series we need to add the previous 2 numbers, and the beginning two numbers are 0 and 1, so they are stored at beginning as there is no other way to get those two number. Now as per your question

```
fib = fib + a;
   a = fib;
}
return fib;
```

the above line of code means that, we are simply adding previous two numbers and saving pointer to it so that we can refer to them. As "fib" will be the previous number and "a" will be previous to previous number and by adding those two number we get the current Fibonacci number and this process continues until the loop ends

This is a bit simpler version of the code that I wrote maybe this helps:

```
public static int fibonacciIterative(int num) {

    int ptp = 0;
    int p = 1;
    int sum = 0;

    if (num == 0) {
        return 0;
    }

    else if (num == 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    else {
        for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++) {

            sum = ptp + p;
            ptp = p;
            p = sum;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

ptp - previous to previous

p - previous

In my code loop starts from 2 because I have handled the case for 0 and 1 using the If conditions

Answer (score -2):

Keep track of fibbonnacci stack with a temporary var to store latest result before switching fib(n-1),fib(n-2) totals. NB: fibb(2) never hits the loop (nobody is perfect)

```
def fibb(n_):
    if n_ < 2:
       return 1
    else
       fun1,fun2,i_= [1,1,2]
       while i_ < n_:
           tmp_= fun1 + fun2
           fun2= fun1
           fun1= tmp_
           i_ += 1 
       return fun1+fun2
```

Comment: This is not written in Java but in Python.

Comment: bruh you can't just copy answers and post it again.